# What is unique about application development projects?

Tags: agile, communication, pmp, ms-project-2010, pmi-framework

I'd like to understand the difference, from a project-management perspective, between application development and other, non-application development.

Comment: Unclear what the purpose of your question is. Are you asking what the differences are between developing an application and other development work (and if so, from a development or from a project management viewpoint)? Or are you trying to recruit PMs?

Comment: Hello, yes, from a Project Management perspective and yes, i am actively looking for consultants for (Automotive Client in Dearborn, MI).

Comment: I removed the bits about recruitment from your question - that is off-topic for PMSE.

Comment: I pretty sure that "Application development" is a very broad field, but what exactly is "non-application development"? Do you mean "non-development" as in plumbing or lawn-moving? Or actually "non-software development" as in developing photos using chemicals? There is really nothing you could develop in software that you could not call an "Application".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl; dr

90% of project management is communications. 90% of communications is trust.  The more relevant experience the PM has, the easier it is to gain and retain the trust of the team.

### discursive rambling

From a pure project management standpoint, all projects are the same.  The goal is the same; to close the project on time, on budget, on quality.

That said, a PM with software development experience will be more effective at

- estimating software development time and effort,
- establishing WBS & WBSD,
- identifying, assessing and analyzing risks,
- developing mitigation plans,
- identifying, assessing and disposing of issues,
- identifying and managing technical debt,
- establishing and evaluating quality standards,
- working closely with developers and in a development culture,
- **applying** the project management methodology to the team and project in question.